# Can't get admin access for getFiles and getDirectories

Tags: c#, wpf, administrator, getfiles, getdirectories

I've been trying to write a filesearcher in c# wpf with `getFiles` and `getDirectories` and it was ok when I was reading files from desktop, etc. But when I was trying to read the `c:\`, I got an access denied error. So I've edited my `.manifest` file to `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`, but the problem is still there. Is there something more to do to gain administrator privileges?

Comment: try compiling your application in x86 and x64 any one of the mode might do the trick.

Comment: Didn't help... Nothing changed.